# Have dual boot Win7 & Mint 17.3, how to install Ubuntu over Mint?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, mint

I have a laptop that currently dual boots Windows 7 and Mint 17.3.

I want to try Ubuntu and want to replace Mint with Ubuntu.  Is there a way to do this without destroying Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to try Ubuntu without installing by creating a live install on either DVD or USB - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check on which partition you have Mint installed.
You can do this in Mint with this command:

`$ sudo fdisk -l`

In the Output you will see something like this:

`Device Boot     Start         End     Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1           2048    31459327   15728640   83   Linux
/dev/sda2       31459328   209715199   89127936   83   WIN`

Note the device where Linux (Mint) is running and start a live install like mentioned in the comments above. During the installation it will ask you on which partition you want to install Ubuntu. Select the the one you've noted.

Comment: Aka "it just works".  I'm not sure why I didn't assume that it would just work out of the box!